# Компилятор С++ добавляет странные символы к именам функций

Tags: c++, name-mangling

Игрался с gcc и g++ и заметил вот такой интересный момент

Есть исходник

```
int
start()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Компилирую его с помощью gcc -c и использую объектник для просмотра таблицы имён с помощью nm
как и ожидалось получаю

```
00000000 T start
```

Если компилировать тот же файл с g++ и просмотреть таблицу имён в объектнике, то видим

```
00000000 T _Z5startv
```

Ну и собственно вопрос. Зачем g++ искажает имя функции? есть ли в этом смысл и делают ли так другие c++ компиляторы?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Он не искажает. Он делает замангливания имен. Это нужно с одной целью - в Си нет перегрузки функций - там не может быть двух функций с одинаковым именем и разными сингнатурами (наборами параметров). А вот в с++ - может. И каждый компилятор делает это по своему. В линуксе для gcc есть утилита `c++filt` которая умеет делать такое преобразование. Для Visual Studio есть утилита `Undname.exe` которая идет в стандартной поставке.

В тех случаях, когда такое поведение нежелательно, применяют [extern "C"](http://alex-siew.livejournal.com/2489.html).

Comment: @KoVadim
Спасибо большое.
И доп вопрос:
т.е. если я хочу сам указать как точку входа некоторую функци юто мне нужно либо объявлять её с extern "c" либо лазать nm и смотреть как она выглядит в объектнике и больше никак?

Comment: точкой входа вместо main?

Comment: @KoVadim да, именно так

Comment: я думаю, что нужно прописать правильное имя. Но лазить постоянно не нужно - форматов то всегда два. Раз уж у Вас есть такая необходимость - проверьте, как оно работает.

Answer (score 3):

Это нужно для реализации таких особенностей С++, как, например, перегрузка функций и шаблоны.

Answer (score 1):

На Википедии достаточно написано про [Name mangling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) особенно в External links. 
Рекомендую почитать,  например,  в конце добавляются типы параметров функции: i-int, c-char и т. д.  А число после _Z это длина имени функции